# Hibernate info messages are doubled

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, startup

Hibernate during an initial start of the spring-boot application. Started to create a table, my issue is that info messages in the log are doubled. It makes logs file redundant. Does anyone solve this issue?

```
2018-02-07 12:38:36.516  INFO 4684 --- [ost-startStop-1] rmationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl : HHH000262: Table not found: **si_binary_storage**
2018-02-07 12:38:36.517  INFO 4684 --- [ost-startStop-1] rmationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl : HHH000262: Table not found: **si_binary_storage**

2018-02-07 12:38:36.547  INFO 4684 --- [ost-startStop-1] rmationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl : HHH000262: Table not found: **sic_category**
2018-02-07 12:38:36.547  INFO 4684 --- [ost-startStop-1] rmationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl : HHH000262: Table not found: **sic_category**

2018-02-07 12:38:36.573  INFO 4684 --- [ost-startStop-1] rmationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl : HHH000262: Table not found: **sic_categorytemplate**
2018-02-07 12:38:36.575  INFO 4684 --- [ost-startStop-1] rmationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl : HHH000262: Table not found: **sic_categorytemplate**
...
```

> ```
> #**Application.properties** 
>
> spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
> spring.datasource.validation-query=select 1 from dual
>
> # Configuration of HSQL DB, it is used only when si.properties is not available 
> spring.datasource.url: jdbc:hsqldb:file:${java.io.tmpdir}/sitoolkit/build/db/simdr.db
> spring.datasource.username=sa
> spring.datasource.password=*****
> spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
> spring.jpa.show-sql=false
>
> server.port=spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect_resolvers=de.usu.si.toolkit.SIDialectResolver
>
> flyway.enabled=false
> ```

Comment: It would help if you show us your logging configuration (probably from `application.properties` or some other config file)

Comment: there is no more configuration related to hibernate, I guess it should be some where in my code. I tried to search for it but without success.